# Как сверстать адаптивный круг с геометрическими фигурами

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

в .psd [файле](https://drive.google.com/file/d/150mMgYZXVrK9k31zmz7G8AvFI68cros_/view) есть такой фрагмент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю как сверстать этот блок, потому что это не картинка, а несколько блоков (линии, круги, треугольник)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cls-1 {
  fill: #fff;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-4 {
  stroke: #ededed;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.cls-2,
.cls-3 {
  fill: #ededed;
}

.cls-3 {
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}

.cls-4 {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg id="something" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="79.094" height="78" viewBox="0 0 79.094 78">
  <circle class="cls-1" cx="39" cy="39" r="37"/>
  <rect class="cls-2" x="1" y="39" width="24" height="4"/>
  <path id="Polygon_1" data-name="Polygon 1" class="cls-3" d="M589.128,2739.5l-19.3-10.66,18.881-11.38Z" transform="translate(-550 -2688)"/>
  <path class="cls-3" d="M600.916,2716.71l3.369-2.16,24.8,38.74-3.369,2.16Z" transform="translate(-550 -2688)"/>
  <circle class="cls-4" cx="43" cy="25" r="23"/>
  <path class="cls-3" d="M569.3,2756.59l52.591-26.74,1.813,3.56-52.591,26.74Z" transform="translate(-550 -2688)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: вставьте svg/png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил

Comment: @MaximLensky, спасибо, понятно

Comment: а что значит сверстать ? просто вставьте этот код в html и это будет работать даже там где html5 не работает

Comment: @MaximLensky я не подумал об этом, что можно взять svg из .psd макета, теперь мне это не нужно верстать

Comment: ну конечно не нужно ..у вас же готовый код ..